# What is the difference between these two form of .new code in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

new to ruby on rails.
have no idea on what's the difference on these two lines.

```
validation_code = ValidationCode.new { |v| v.email = params[:email], v.kind = 'sign_in', v.verify_code = code  }
validation_code = ValidationCode.new email: params[:email], kind: 'sign_in', verify_code: code
```

ask this is because I'm getting two different result.

```
def create
    code = SecureRandom.random_number.to_s[2..7]
    validation_code = ValidationCode.new { |v| v.email = params[:email], v.kind = 'sign_in', v.verify_code = code  }
    # validation_code = ValidationCode.new email: params[:email], kind: 'sign_in', verify_code: code
    if validation_code.save
        render status: 200
    else
        render json:{errors: validation_code.errors}, status: 400
    end
end
```

first written will return status 200, and second written will return status 400. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So first, the first one is using the block form of ActiveRecord's initialize method, [see more in the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).  There's no real difference to how each works, it's really just a style choice.

**Your** problem here is that the code you've included in your block isn't doing what you think it is because you're using commas to try to separate each statement.  Ruby isn't seeing what you think it is, take a look at what `v.email` equals after that assignment.  It will be an array of the email AND the other two elements!

Answer (score 1):

This is how the difference looks visually:

```rb
# With keyword arguments

validation_code = ValidationCode.new email: params[:email], kind: 'sign_in', verify_code: code

validation_code.email == params[:email]
# => true

validation_code.kind == 'sign_in'
# => true

validation_code.verify_code == code
# => true
```

```rb
# With block

validation_code = ValidationCode.new { |v| v.email = params[:email], v.kind = 'sign_in', v.verify_code = code  }

validation_code.email == [params[:email], 'sign_in', code].to_s
# => true

validation_code.kind == 'sign_in'
# => true

validation_code.verify_code == code
# => true
```

Because Ruby read it as

```rb
validation_code = ValidationCode.new { |v| v.email = [params[:email], v.kind = 'sign_in', v.verify_code = code]  }
```

Pay attention that Rails do not just assign an array value to `email`, but convert it to string

So in fact email is something like `"[\"email@email.com\", \"sign_in\", 1234]"`

If you want both lines to work the same, then the line with the block can be written as

```rb
validation_code = ValidationCode.new { |v| v.email = params[:email]; v.kind = 'sign_in'; v.verify_code = code  }
```

or better multi-line

```rb
validation_code =
  ValidationCode.new do |v|
    v.email = params[:email]
    v.kind = 'sign_in'
    v.verify_code = code
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Both forms of `new` do the same thing (though your code does not) just in different ways.

`model = Model.new(key1: value1, key2: value2)` makes a new object, initializes it with the given values, and returns the new object.

```
model = Model.new { |m|
  m.key1 = value1
  m.key2 = value2
}
```

Makes a new object, and passes it to the block uninitialized. The block can now initialize the object in any way it pleases. Then the new, initialized object is returned.

The block form just offers more flexibility.

---

Why not just write this?

```
model = Model.new
model.key1 = value1
model.key2 = value2
```

If there is an `after_initialize` callback it will be called after `new` and before the object is initialized. That may cause problems because the object is not yet initialized.

But its really for [`create`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create):

```
model = Model.create
model.key1 = value1
model.key2 = value2
```

`create` will [call many callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object) on the uninitialized object, and it may violate database constraints such as `not null`.

---

Back to your code: the problem is you've tried to separate statements with commas in order to cram it into one line.

```
validation_code = ValidationCode.new { |v| 
  v.email = params[:email], v.kind = 'sign_in', v.verify_code = code
                          ^                   ^
}
```

`v.kind` and `v.verify_code` are fine, but `v.email` is an Array. You don't need the `[]` to make an Array. Ruby has parsed your code as:

```
v.email = [ params[:email], v.kind = 'sign_in', v.verify_code = code ]
```

Let's do the equivalent in IRB.

```
3.1.2 :001 > a = 4, b = 8, c = 12
 => [4, 8, 12] 
3.1.2 :002 > a
 => [4, 8, 12] 
3.1.2 :003 > b
 => 8 
3.1.2 :004 > c
 => 12 
3.1.2 :005 >
```

Instead, use semicolons to separate statements.

```
validation_code = ValidationCode.new { |v| 
  v.email = params[:email]; v.kind = 'sign_in'; v.verify_code = code
}
```

Better yet, use newlines for clarity.

```
validation_code = ValidationCode.new { |v| 
  v.email = params[:email]
  v.kind = 'sign_in'
  v.verify_code = code
}
```